# Would it be unethical to not cite a figure obtained from a Q&A forum?

Tags: publications, citations, ethics, plagiarism

We are writing an article in which we should give a figure (a satellite image; not a real map) to make the 'preliminary' section complete and understandable.

However, drawing the image ourselves is not possible. However, as the image is related to a well-known problem, it is available in various Q & A forums. The same image can be found in multiple such forums and we do not know the original source of the image.

In such a scenario,

- Would it be unethical to not cite the forum in our research paper?
- If we must cite any of the available forum links, how are we supposed to cite the image?

Comment: Including it without permission of the rights holder is likely a copyright violation, even if you cite it. (Though you might be able to argue that it's fair use)

Comment: @CodesInChaos, that depends largely on the country you reside in. Many countries allow the citing of whole works in research, explicitly giving the advance in research a  priority over copyrights.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Would it be unethical to not cite the forum in our research paper?

**Yes, of course it would!**  Similarly, it would be unethical to use a figure without citation from a student's written exam, a newspaper article, a billboard on the side of the highway, a 3000-year-old clay tablet, or a bathroom wall.  If you do not cite the source of the figure, you are falsely claiming that the figure is your own work.  You **must** give other people credit for their work, no matter how you find it.

> If we must cite any of the available forum links, how are we supposed to cite the image?

You are *supposed* to find the original source of the figure, and cite that.  Of course, finding the original source may not be possible, but you do need to make a serious good-faith effort.  (I suggest asking "What's the source of this image?" on the same forums where you find the image.)  If that good-faith effort fails, cite whatever secondary source you believe is most authoritative and/or most likely to be accessible to the average reader in five years.  For example:

[1] Unknown author.  http://three-d-pancakes.ytmnd.com/.  Accessed June 24, 2017.

Comment: +1 for the oddly disturbing example (as well as a clear concise answer in general, of course).

Comment: Original source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1R3G_beQccA

Comment: +1. Great, thank you. I mailed the "contact" guys at the bottom of the page for permission. Thank you for the bibliography for such a reference.

Comment: Today I received the email from these guys. It says that I should contact the original source of the image, specifically, the person who posted in their forum. For that, I have to visit, the intended person's account and email him/her (if at all, the address is available). I am almost dead. I feel, *I should draw the image myself.* This is hell lot of time to waste.